# Visual Studio (c++), Missing variable in map file for release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am building code in both debug and release mode using visual studio 2005 C++.
I need to generate map file for a dll to get some address.
I have a global buffer FREE_MEM in one of my header file.

my problem is when I use debug mode I get proper address in map file for my buffer e.g. _FREE_MEM 0x00... but when I use release mode the variable disappears from map file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve the issue by initializing my buffer
FREE_MEM = "";

also I have move the variable to a .C file from header file.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't verify this directly, I suspect that if you decorate the variable definition with [_dllexport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx) it will be exported and therefore will be listed in the map file.